# How to wait for forEach containing async function call to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, xmlhttprequest

I have a forEach with an XMLHttpRequest in it and I want to do something after all requests in that loop have finished. (I want to add an event listener for each element I've added after the loop).

I actually have a function that wraps XMLHttpRequest, which is:

```
function requestAPI(method, url, token = null, json = null, callback = null) {
  const rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType('application/json');
  rawFile.open(method, url, true);
  if (token != null) {
    rawFile.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Token ${token}`);
  }
  rawFile.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8;');
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(rawFile);
      callback(rawFile);
    }
  };
  rawFile.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}
```

And then my loop is something like:

```
campaigns.forEach((campaign, campaignIndex) => {
    requestAPI('GET', `${API_ADDRESS}/call1/`, token, None, (response1) => {
        // code to add element to page
    });
});
```

Comment: does it need to be in the campaign foreach? I see nowhere you use anything from the campaign in the ajax call

Comment: Have `requestAPI` return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or use `fetch()`, then use `Promise.all()`. This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cLs4ohy5/ (note that you were passing `rawFile` to your callback)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG!